# Cannot resolve this error: "Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel-6

Many people have asked about this error: Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist. It seems to have many root causes, but I cannot determine my root cause.
I am using Laravel 6.20.43. The software does not produce any errors when run in the browser.

## The error

The error appears when I use this command: `php artisan db:seed`

Here is DatabaseSeeder.php:

```
<?php

namespace Database\seeds;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // factory$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        // factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();
        // dd('DatabaseSeeder.php TESTING...');
    }
}
```

## What have I tried?

- I have tried to add a dd(...) inside DatabaseSeeder::run(). The dd(...) is not executed.
- I have tried `composer update`. The update was performed nicely, but did not resolve the error.
- I have tried several use clauses in DatabaseSeeder.php.
- I have tried `php artisan migrate:fresh`
- I have tried several combinations of solutions, for example to run migrations before dump-autoload and vice versa.
- I have tried `composer dump-autoload` and this is the output:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
Generated optimized autoload files containing 4381 classes
```

- I have tried to redirect the output of `php artisan db:seed` to xdebug so I can analyse step by step what is happening. Good luck is what I needed here, but I ran out of luck.
- I have tried to examine the error using `php artisan db:seed -vvv`. Here is the full output:

```
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist.

  at /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
    801| 
    802|         try {
    803|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    804|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  > 805|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    806|         }
    807| 
    808|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    809|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  Exception trace:

  1   ReflectionException::("Class DatabaseSeeder does not exist")
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803

  2   ReflectionClass::__construct()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803

  3   Illuminate\Container\Container::build()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:681

  4   Illuminate\Container\Container::resolve()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:785

  5   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::resolve()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:629

  6   Illuminate\Container\Container::make()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:770

  7   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::make()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php:76

  8   Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand::getSeeder()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php:63

  9   Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand::Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\{closure}()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:129

  10  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguarded()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php:64

  11  Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand::handle()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36

  12  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:37

  13  Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93

  14  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37

  15  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:590

  16  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:134

  17  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255

  18  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:121

  19  Illuminate\Console\Command::run()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1009

  20  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273

  21  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149

  22  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:93

  23  Illuminate\Console\Application::run()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:131

  24  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
      /home/billybob/laravel-cursus1/artisan:37
```

I truly cannot understand how to debug the output of `php artisan db:seed -vvv`. All those files reside in the vendor directory, meaning I cannot examine the program flow easily. Please also explain how I can debug such an error by myself in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot find your `DatabaseSeeder` class because your namespace is incorrect.

You need to change the namespace of your `DatabaseSeeder` class from:

```
namespace Database\seeds;
```

to:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;
```

Make sure your composer autoload is setup correctly:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
  }
}
```

**Alternatively**, completely remove ***all namespaces*** from your `DatabaseSeeder` class and revert the above changes to `composer.json` and then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

then try running:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: I tried changing the namespace to Database\Seeders. Then I tried composer dump-autoload and php artisan migrate:fresh and php artisan db:seed. The result is the same: "Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist.".

Comment: @MasinJay See my update. Make sure your composer autoload is setup correctly.

Comment: still the same error message. When I put the mouse cursor on "database/seeders", then PHPStorm says "Path not found". However when I change it to "database/seeds", then the warning disappears. Still the original error still persists. This concerns a brand new Laravel 6 installation; I only added some migration files and models and classes so far. Then I implemented your suggestions.

Comment: @MasinJay did you try my **alternative** suggestion?

Comment: I read your alternative suggestion only after I posted my comment. Now I tried your alternative suggestion. That did the trick. Could you explain what exactly was the problem? Should I now remove all namespaces that produce errors?

Comment: @MasinJay earlier versions of Laravel may not have enforced a namespace. And so when you and I both set namespaces it threw the autoloader off hence your error. What I would suggest is to exclude the namespaces.